# Can I add a horizontal marker to the Graph Editor?

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

I would like to add a horizontal marker to the Graph Editor. I'm going to animate an integer value which represents an index into an array of meshes. I want to have a visual reference of the size of the array so that I can quickly position keyframes based on it. I imagine that the horizontal marker would look something like this:

[image]

It looks like vertical markers are already supported? Is there a built-in solution for adding a horizontal marker? Or can I use Python to add one?

Comment: Hi. Can you explain why you need this? Understanding why you need this might allow us to suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: @RayMairlot I'm going to animate an integer value which represents an index into an array of meshes. I want to have a visual reference of the size of the array so that I can quickly position keyframes based on it.